# EditText Next Focus is not woking

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have few `EditText` in a same screen. `Next soft key button` is not there. Enter soft key is there but, it was not going to next EditText whenever I am pressing on that button. And after last EditText reached, I want to hide the soft keyboard. What should I do to achieve that. I found many questions and solution in stackoverflow. Nothing working for me.

Edittext Code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext|actionGo|actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:hint="GA-00-A0000"
        android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/vehicle_color"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_rect_yellow_border" />
```

Tried java code also,

```
vehicle_number.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.vehicle_color);
```

Comment: what about `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/vehicle_color"`

Comment: Than you @IntelliJ Amiya. Tried. Not working. I think due to this line "android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-" " the next soft key not showing.

Comment: May be .For test case set `android:imeOptions=actionNext"`

Comment: Now it was working next button is there. But, without this "flagNoExtractUi" the editText occupying full screen while typing. I can't see the design or next or previous fields.

Comment: Actually `Conflicting` yours `android:imeOptions`

Comment: Then, what should I do for this bug. Any other way is there to fix this.

Comment: You should use only one .you can try with `android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"` .I assume `flagNoExtractUi` creating problems

Comment: Please see the edited question. I am using same in different screen or layout. There it was working.

Comment: Then problem for `android:inputType` or `android:digits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed myself. The solution is below. Now the 'Next' soft key displaying.

**Removed**

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

**Added**

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
```

**For Capital Characters**

```
vehicle_number.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

**Solution**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:hint="GA-00-A0000"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:digits="1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm-"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_rect_yellow_border" />
```